# How can I select lattest 3 posts in a certain category in WordPress using a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Hello everyone i'm a complete noob on mysql 
and i have this dump wordpress mysql database where i have to pull out the latest three posts all this done with mysql.

searching here when i execute this query

```
    SELECT *
FROM   wp_terms t
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt
              ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE  tt.taxonomy = 'category'
ORDER  BY name
```

it gets me as a result all the categories. i want a query who pulls me out the latest 3 posts from a single category only... 
i've found this code and more or less it gets executed,

```
    SELECT *
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND p.post_type = 'post'
  AND t.slug = 'guide'
  limit 3
```

any better idea? some documentation where i can search by?

Comment: Why not builtin functions `get_posts()` , `query_posts()` ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i have only the mysql dump backup database and i have to work only with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go to get 3 latest post in specific category

```
SELECT 
  p.* 
FROM
  wp_posts p 
  JOIN wp_term_relationships r 
    ON r.object_id = p.ID 
  JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt 
    ON tt.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id 
  JOIN wp_terms t 
    ON tt.term_id = t.term_id 
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND p.post_type = 'post' 
  AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' 
  AND t.term_id = 2 /* <--- Put your category id here */
ORDER BY p.ID DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f46457d/2)